# Using android sdk windows files for mac

Tags: android

I have installed android sdk version 22 on my windows. all the api is installed on my windows. They are about 7GB.

Now I want to develop android on mac mountain lion. I now that in windows you can copy apis from one machine to another machine and use them without downloading them again.

What about mac. Can I reuse these files on the mac?

Comment: No! I dont think so the frameworks are different.

Comment: delete `tools`, `platform-tools`, `build-tools` folders and `SDK Manager.exe` + `AVD Manager.exe` run SDK Manager for MAC and it should work(only 200MB to download)

Comment: Thanks selvin, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and in a way NO.

You can reuse the add-ons, docs, extras, platforms, samples,sources and system-images.

In simpler words, download the adt bundle for mac and add the platforms and system-images to the sdk folder in mac. You will have all your sdk versions there.